# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while executing in spring

Tags: java, eclipse

getting error of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` while executing the submit button, the compilation was really successfull and the build/class/

Error

```
-------
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@31809212: defining beans [crunchifyHelloWorld,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 17, 2015 2:09:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/crunchify/controller/PasswordCheck
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
```

src/com/crunchify/controller/CrunchifyHelloWorld.java

---

```
package com.crunchify.controller;

import com.crunchify.controller.PasswordCheck;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.validation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
/*
 * author: Crunchify.com
 * 
 */

@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>" + 
                         "<h3>********** Welcome to LDO Support Landing page **********<h3> </div><br><br>";
        return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView addContact(@ModelAttribute("index")
      com.crunchify.controller.PasswordCheck passcheck, BindingResult result) {

            System.out.println("userid:" + passcheck.getUser_id() + "password:" + passcheck.getPassword());

                //return "redirect:contacts.html";
            String message = "<br><div style='text-align:center;'>" + 
                     "<h3>********** Welcome to LDO Support Landing page **********<h3> </div><br><br>";

                return new ModelAndView("welcome", "message", message);
        }


}
```

src/com/crunchify/controller/PasswordCheck.java

```
package com.crunchify.controller;

public class PasswordCheck {

    private String user_id;
    private String password;
    public String getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/1119381

Comment: Can you do ctrl+shift+t this will show a class file if created at all. If not probably u need to clean and build

Comment: yes ctrl+shift+t shows the class file.

Comment: perhaps compiled with an incompatible (too new) java version? do you have other classes that work OK ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Spring, you should annotate the `PasswordCheck` as `@Service` or `@Component` and make it available in the controller via `@Resource`.
This should make it available, since the Controller is being instantiated while the context loads, your component scan will not have detected the `PasswordCheck`-class at that time.
So, you should do this:

```
@Service
public class PasswordCheck {
    // code omitted
}
```

and

```
@Controller
public class CrunchifyHelloWorld {

    @Resource
    private PasswordCheck passwordCheck;
```

and use the bean name "`passwordCheck`" in your method.